# timezone() missing required argument 'offset' (pos 1) in models.py while trying to migrate, what is the reason?

Tags: python, django

while making a blog, my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    author=models.ForeignKey('auth.user',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='media/',blank=True)
    content=models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True)
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, editable=False)
    tag=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    slug=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

when i run **python manage.py makemigrations**, datefield is created in database:

```
from django.db import migrations, models
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
dependencies = [
    ('blog', '0013_auto_20191124_1448'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='post',
        name='date',
        field=models.DateTimeField(editable=False),
    ),
]
```

but when i try to run **python manage.py migrate**, it shows the following error:

```
(Django-k7xSBAPV) C:\Myfiles\python\Django\myblog\blog_project>python manage.py 
makemigrations
No changes detected

(Django-k7xSBAPV) C:\.....\blog_project>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying blog.0004_post_date...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
main()
File "manage.py", line 17, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\ronyrocks\.virtualenvs\Django-k7xSBAPV\lib\site-
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in 
execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\ronyrocks\.virtualenvs\Django-k7xSBAPV\lib\site-
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\ronyrocks\.virtualenvs\Django-k7xSBAPV\lib\site-
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Users\ronyrocks\.virtualenvs\Django-k7xSBAPV\lib\site-
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Users\ronyrocks\.virtualenvs\Django-k7xSBAPV\lib\site-
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped 
res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ronyrocks\.virtualenvs\Django-k7xSBAPV\lib\site-
packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 234, in handle
fake_initial=fake_initial,
File "C:\Users\ronyrocks\.virtualenvs\Django-k7xSBAPV\lib\site-
packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, 
fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\ronyrocks\.virtualenvs\Django-k7xSBAPV\lib\site-
packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, 
fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\ronyrocks\.virtualenvs\Django-k7xSBAPV\lib\site-
packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "C:\Users\ronyrocks\.virtualenvs\Django-k7xSBAPV\lib\site-
packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, 
project_state)
File "C:\Users\ronyrocks\.virtualenvs\Django-k7xSBAPV\lib\site-
packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 112, in database_forwards field,
File "C:\Users\ronyrocks\.virtualenvs\Django-k7xSBAPV\lib\site-
packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 327, in add_field
self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
File "C:\Users\ronyrocks\.virtualenvs\Django-k7xSBAPV\lib\site-
packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 188, in _reremake_table
self.effective_default(create_field)
File "C:\Users\ronyrocks\.virtualenvs\Django-k7xSBAPV\lib\site-
packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 233, in effectctive_default
return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
File "C:\Users\ronyrocks\.virtualenvs\Django-k7xSBAPV\lib\site-
packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 212, in _effecective_default
default = field.get_default()
File "C:\Users\ronyrocks\.virtualenvs\Django-k7xSBAPV\lib\site-
packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 801, in get_t_default
return self._get_default()
TypeError: timezone() missing required argument 'offset' (pos 1)
```

but without date in models.py, everything was working fine. i tried to use dafault=timezone.now() along with from django.utils.timezone import * but it's showing different warning.

please give me some suggestions. i am doing this in django2.2.

Comment: The problem is not with your latest migration but with 0004 `Applying blog.0004_post_date`. if you've already applied the previous 12 migrations then your `migrate` command shouldn't have tried to apply 0004. Check your `django_migrations` table in your database and check how many of your migrations has been applied.

Comment: thanx for your effort, homie....is there any way we can chat or communicate? i can use some helps...please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i solved the problem. i am sharing it if anyone wish to look through.... and i have polished the code...

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author=models.ForeignKey(
                        'auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='media/',blank=True)
    content=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    tag=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.title
    def publish_time(self):
       publication=timezone.now()
       self.save()
```

My main issue was i forget to migrate when i first created the app. i am not sure this is the main reason or not. but it worked smoothly.besides i have decided to use ckeditor, but it poses another problem which it just accepts picture from the link. that's why i prefer more ImageField....

any way this model.py file ran at first attempt while starting a clean app.

thanx again

Comment: Ckeditor can upload files via browse-upload,copy-paste, and drag-drop. I think you might had some problem implementing ckeditor.  Response to your problem: ckeditor, but it poses another problem which it just accepts picture from the link.